# Can I use an IFrame to navigate to an external page in a Windows 8 Metro application?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

When I currently try I get the following error, even after adding google as a content URI

APPHOST9613: The App Host was unable to navigate to http://www.google.com/ due to the following error: FORBIDFRAMING.

Comment: Can you show the exact code of your `iframe` (and supporting JS code, if you're navigating programmatically)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On further investigation the answer seem to be that yes you can for most sites, but some sites (such as google) seem to fail when embedding with an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Response from MSFT:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/a1cba639-3251-4df8-abd3-b6f6a95ba4ae

Answer (score 1):

You can use Iframe,but you won't get full controll of their JS files,you may have to face some breaking point in such sites, and some sites like google blocking this facility.

Try this,
1. Make your default browser as IE10 which will provide you an App look for IE.
2. trigger an event

```
function openYourLink() {    
    var url = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("http://www.google.com")
    Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe to navigate to other pages.

```
<iframe src="http://www.apple.com" />
```

will do the trick.

However, not every website allows you to put their page in an iframe or they maybe using the top window layer so that their page doesn't support running in an iframe.

In addition, if you are running your code Visual Studio 11 Express, it may throw javascript exceptions in the web page in the iframe. You can "continue" it. This exception will not be visible when you are running a deployed version of your application (running from start menu).